# Verify in python if a thread exists before it run or in a while True

Tags: python, multithreading

I have some process running in threads in my python script
but id like to know if this process stops for any reason and try to execute it again.
How to do that ?

my code:

main.py

```
from functions import Functions
func = Functions()
func.checkRoiProcess(roi_list) # this function call a thread
while True:
    # this is where i must to check if this tread still running
    #if func.checkRoiProcess still running:
    #    do some thing
    #else:
    #    execute thread again
```

in my functions.py

```
def checkRoiProcess(self,ROI):      
        Thread(target = self.checkRoiChanges, args = (ROI,), daemon=True).start()
```

any one can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the `Thread` object from the `checkRoiProcess` method.

```
def checkRoiProcess(self,ROI):      
        roi_thread = Thread(target = self.checkRoiChanges, args = (ROI,), daemon=True)
        roi_thread.start()
        return roi_thread
```

And use the [`is_alive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive) method to check if the thread is still running:

```
roi_thread = func.checkRoiProcess(roi_list)
while True:
    if roi_thread.is_alive():
    #    do some thing
    else:
    #    execute thread again
```